# New Facebook action can't be published with Test Users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I've created a Facebook action that I'm trying to submit to Facebook for approval. When I publish the action from my personal account, which is an app administrator, it appears to work fine and Facebook returns the Open Graph ID. I don't see this Open Graph Post on my timeline, but I can see that it works via the [Facebook Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

However, when I try to post the action via a test user that I created from my app settings, I get an error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1fc64d60 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 100;
            message = "Unsupported post request.";
            type = GraphMethodException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}
```

I've tried tried debugging this for days and can't figure out what this error means. I know that when Facebook reviews the action, they will be doing it from a test user as well, so I want to make sure that my action works with test users. If it's relevant, I'm posting the action via the iOS SDK.

Any help in troubleshooting this would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, posting from a test user should be fine. Can you post some code snippets on how you're doing the post?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your app is still in testing / sandbox mode. Make sure that your application is public and try again .

Comment: The app is already in production, with real users using the app to login every day. Test accounts are able to login to the app using the test account, they just can post any of the new actions.